# Logistic regression + histogram with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, logistic-regression

I have some binary data, and I want to plot both a logistic regression line *and* the histogram of relative frequencies of 0s and 1s in the same plot.

I ran into a very nice implementation using the package popbio here: [shizuka lab's page](http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/plotting-logistic-regression-in-r)

Here a MWE that runs with library(popbio) (courtesy shizuka lab)

```
bodysize=rnorm(20,30,2) # generates 20 values, with mean of 30 & s.d.=2
bodysize=sort(bodysize) # sorts these values in ascending order.
survive=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1) # assign 'survival' to these 20 individuals non-randomly... most mortality occurs at smaller body size
dat=as.data.frame(cbind(bodysize,survive))

#and now the plot
library(popbio)
logi.hist.plot(bodysize,survive,boxp=FALSE,type="hist",col="gray")
```

which produces

[image]

#### Now, is it possible to do this with ggplot2?

Comment: ggplot and double y-axis are 'difficult by philosophy' , but something similar might be possible.

Comment: @Heroka and I agree with the philosopy -- I usually try not to use them. Still, I can see that in this case it makes a lot of sense -- you get a real sense of the data, while with the geom_smooth()+geom_point() you see only one point and not the mass of points, so you have no clear idea of the data. I tried geom_smooth()+geom_point(position='jitter') but in my case I have a lot of data and the jitter getsa ll over the place.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some idea's

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bodysize, y = survive)) + 
  geom_dotplot(
    aes(fill = factor(survive)), method = "histodot", binpositions = "all", 
    stackgroups = TRUE, stackdir = "centerwhole", binwidth = 1
  ) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", family = "binomial")

ggplot(dat, aes(x = bodysize, y = survive)) + 
  geom_hex(bins = 10) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", family = "binomial")

ggplot(dat, aes(x = bodysize, y = survive)) + 
  geom_bin2d(bins = 10) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", family = "binomial")
```

Comment: +1 for the large array of possibilities but still not getting there. I mean, they are all nice and well but they are not as readable as the popbio example.

Comment: A more elaborate solution would be to calculate the histograms. Then calculate the coordinates of the bars of the histograms. Then use those coordinates in `geom_rect()`.

Comment: `geom_smooth()` now takes `family` as a list of method.args:

 `geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"))`